# Referring to numbers in data table columns' names in a loop

Tags: r, loops, indexing, data.table

I have a dataset like here:

```
customer_id <- c("1","1","1","2","2","2","2","3","3","3")
account_id <- as.character(c(11,11,11,55,55,55,55,38,38,38))
time <- c(as.Date("2017-01-01","%Y-%m-%d"), as.Date("2017-02-01","%Y-%m-%d"), as.Date("2017-03-01","%Y-%m-%d"),
              as.Date("2017-12-01","%Y-%m-%d"), as.Date("2018-01-01","%Y-%m-%d"), as.Date("2018-02-01","%Y-%m-%d"),
              as.Date("2018-03-01","%Y-%m-%d"), as.Date("2018-04-01","%Y-%m-%d"), as.Date("2018-05-01","%Y-%m-%d"),
              as.Date("2018-06-01","%Y-%m-%d"))
tenor <- c(1,2,3,1,2,3,4,1,2,3)
variable_x <- c(87,90,100,120,130,150,12,13,15,14)

my_data <- data.table(customer_id,account_id,time,tenor,variable_x)
```

Now, I would like to create new variables "PD_Q1" up to "PD_Q20" that would equal to the value of "variable_x" when "tenor" is equal to 1 up to 20, i.e., PD_Q1 equal to variable_x's value if tenor = 1, PD_Q2 equal to variable_x's value if tenor = 2, etc. and I would like to do that by customer_id, account_id. I have the code for that, however only for PD_Q1 and I would like to make a loop that loops over i = 1:20 in which I change just tenor == i (this one is easy) and refer to columns PD_Qi in this loop, which is a problem for me. The code for one value of i is here:

```
my_data[tenor == 1, PD_Q1_temp := variable_x, by = c("customer_id", "account_id")]

list_accs <- my_data[tenor == 1, c("customer_id", "account_id", "PD_Q1_temp")]

list_accs <- unique(list_accs, by = c("customer_id", "account_id"))

names(list_accs) = c("customer_id", "account_id", "PD_Q1")

my_data = merge(x = my_data, y = list_accs, by = c("customer_id", "account_id"), all.x = TRUE)

my_data$PD_Q1_temp <- NULL
```

Now, can you please advise how to make a loop from 1 to 20, in which tenor, PD_Q1_temp and PD_Q1 would change? Specifically, I don't know how to refer to column names or variables using this i index within a loop.

The expected output for i = 1 and i = 2 (creating variables PD_Q1 and PD_Q2) is here:

```
> my_data
customer_id account_id       time tenor variable_x PD_Q1 PD_Q2
```

1:           1         11 2017-01-01     1         87    87    90
 2:           1         11 2017-02-01     2         90    87    90
 3:           1         11 2017-03-01     3        100    87    90
 4:           2         55 2017-12-01     1        120   120   130
 5:           2         55 2018-01-01     2        130   120   130
 6:           2         55 2018-02-01     3        150   120   130
 7:           2         55 2018-03-01     4         12   120   130
 8:           3         38 2018-04-01     1         13    13    15
 9:           3         38 2018-05-01     2         15    13    15
10:           3         38 2018-06-01     3         14    13    15

now I want to create PD_Q3, PD_Q4 etc. in a loop using my code above that creates one such variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you show your expected output?

I think you can do what you want with `tidyr::gather()`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

my_data %>%
  tbl_df() %>%
  select(-time) %>%
  mutate(tenor = paste0("PD_Q", tenor)) %>%
  spread(tenor, variable_x)

# # A tibble: 3 x 6
#   customer_id account_id PD_Q1 PD_Q2 PD_Q3 PD_Q4
#   <chr>       <chr>      <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1 1           11            87    90   100    NA
# 2 2           55           120   130   150    12
# 3 3           38            13    15    14    NA
```